# Is it halal to promote web-service providers when I have no control over what content they'll provide?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I have a website for promoting web hosting services to host websites (myhostoffer.com). If a visitor on my website clicks on a link and purchases a service then I will get commission for that.

Some of these web hosting companies allow adult website hosting.

My question is: Since I don't know what customers are going to host on the web hosting companies servers, is it halal for me to promote them and receive the commission?

Comment: Some people who buy knives will use it to harm or kill other people. So is it halal or haram to sell knives?

Comment: Many web hosts actually put up a warning that pornographic websites are not allowed. Just a warning should be enough to discourage people who intend to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a business that can be used for haram, can I work for that? ***Ibn Otheemen*** said,

> If someone rents a house from you to live in it and he smokes in it you don't have any problem but if someone rent from you a room to smoke in it that's forbidden.
>   But you can demand that he will not use it in any forbidden work or you will break the user contract of rent if you want.
>   <sup>— Translated from reference: *Alosool min alm alosool* in Arabic [الاصول من علم الاصول] —</sup>

P.S: I forgot the page number.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not intentionally promoting these websites, if any person visits your site and select any server for pornographies you cannot do anything. Even you are not going to be notified too that what the guy is going to host.

So even if you think you are want to deduct that commission how you would you?
Your web is just routing people to select server according to their need and stuff, so take you commission.

I think you got it?

Comment: But he can clearly show in its **Terms & Conditions** for not to use his server for pornography. He can have control over it.

Answer (score -1):

You must be careful of what you are trying to do brother. I know that money is a big part of life and I totally agree with you, but I really don't wanna disappoint you by saying that it's haram. Yes in many cases, I myself am a mobile app developer and an engineer. I know how the advertisments system work. Let me tell you a story of mine when I was young kid. There was this website where I could play games for free and this website was really addictive. Usually as some websites do, they would have a left and right banner advertisement there. Sometimes I would see games being displayed or products but many time I would see girls who were trying to seduce you with their 3 second GIF's made me start masturbating. The only place I started masturbating was when I clicked the ad and it directly redirected me to a porn site. That was the only and first place where I started this act of haram.

**So it's totally haram when you don't have any control over it!**

Comment: i think he controls what is advertisement itself, seems it is just a text link. so, it is not like in your example/case.