# Do I need any special approach to make a web service Sharia compliant?

Tags: sharia, fiqh, business

Generally, if there are any guidelines to make a web application (available through web browser - like this page) Sharia-compliant?

Note that many of my customers are not muslims.

In my particular case I'm building web service for publishing and editing websites, with assumptions:

1. When registering, one can publish controversial and haram content but only on it's own domain name - [somewhat like here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/is-it-halal-to-promote-web-service-providers-when-i-have-no-control-over-what-co) - should I setup a separate server for Sharia-compliant accounts?
2. Account processing and online payments for the service - should those be not accepted overnight or during Ramadan time?

Comment: I allow haram content, but on user's own domain only, however physically it might be same machine. So I'm considering if I should keep sharia compliant accounts on designated machine.

Comment: I've added to question - that many of my customers are not muslims, so I can't expect them to even know what's haram.